# Is my impact on the ground greater than my weight when I jump from the ground?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, collision, free-body-diagram

Is my impact on the ground greater than my weight when I jump from the ground? Is my impact on the ground greater than my weight when I fall to the ground?
I think it's all over my weight. But I'm not sure.

Comment: Weight and impact are not proper physical terms. Do you maybe mean force? So do you ask: When I jump, do I exert a force greater as $mg$? And when I am falling to the ground, do I exert a force greater than $mg$?

Comment: @Semoi What's your answer?

Comment: Have you ever broken something that could support your weight by jumping on it? (eg a stick)

Comment: @enbin: The question you are asking is unclear to me, and it will be probably unclear to others as well. Therefore, you will **help everybody**, by editing your question. If you don't get it perfect immediately, that's not a problem. The people on SE will help you to improve the question.

Answer (score 1):

Think of a weight hanging from a spring.  When the weight is gently brought down to the equilibrium position of the weight-spring system, the force on the spring is $m\ g$.

However, if the weight is placed at the bottom of the unstretched string and allowed to drop, the weight will drop to twice the displacement of the equilibrium position and the force on the spring will briefly be $2\ m\ g$.

So yes, the force exerted by a falling object will be greater than the force exerted by its weight.  The scenario presented above is equivalent to an object dropped from zero height and the force is double the weight. For elastic collisions, the force exerted by a falling collision will be at least double the force of the object's weight.  The case is not quite as simple with plastic deformation of the objects, but still the force is the rate of change of momentum,  $F=\frac{dp}{dt}$ and will be greater than the weight.